# SQL Filtro para não exibir alguns itens de uma tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Bom dia! tudo beleza? 
No site que estou mexendo, exibe uma lista de países que vem do banco de dados. Porém, houve uma exigência que não se exiba os países sancionados pela OFAC.

Ele chama os países com os seguintes comandos SQL:

```
 var sql = @"
        SELECT
            id, nome_pt AS nome
        FROM loc_pais
        ORDER BY nome_pt
    ";
```

Minha dúvida é ; "consigo colocar um filtro para não exibir esses países que são sancionados, ou seria melhor excluir eles da tabela?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se não tiver, inclua uma coluna na tabela "loc_pais" do tipo "bit", por exemplo "sancionado_ofac" e atualize a tabela com quais países são sancionados (`sancionado_ofac=1`).
Depois só acrescentar um `where sancionado_ofac = 0` na sua query

Comment: vlw meu, vou fazer esse esquema!